# AngularJS ngAnimate works for ng-leave but not for ng-enter

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Recently I've been getting the hang of using AngularJS with CSS animations and that seems to work fine and dandy.  I'm trying to incorporate jQuery to run the animations and have run into some problems.

The exit animation works fine but the enter doesn't.  It does fire off the message in the console, but the animation itself fails to run.  What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  vm = this;
  vm.divExists = true;
  vm.click = function() {
    vm.divExists = !vm.divExists;
  }
});

app.animation('.yeet', [function() {
  return {
    enter: function(element, doneFn) {
      console.log('entering');
      jQuery(element).slideDown(400, doneFn);
    },
    leave: function(element, doneFn) {
      console.log('exiting');
      jQuery(element).slideUp(400, doneFn);
    }
  }
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.2.1" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ngAnimate@*" data-semver="1.4.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">

  <button ng-click="vm.click();">
    Click Me
  </button>
  <div class="yeet" style="background-color:green;" ng-if="vm.divExists">
    <h1>This part should slide in and out with button clicks.</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several more hours of banging my head into my desk, I decided I should go back and research the basics of jQuery.

The animation fails to run because when the element is reintroduced into the DOM, it's already in it's 'finished' animation stage.  Because there's nothing for jQuery to do, it reports itself as done.

To fix this, a single line is necessary to put the element in the initial stage required by jQuery's slideDown animation:  element.css('display', 'none');

Revised code:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  vm = this;
  vm.divExists = true;
  vm.click = function() {
    vm.divExists = !vm.divExists;
  }
});

app.animation('.yeet', [function() {
  return {
    enter: function(element, doneFn) {
      console.log('entering');
      element.css('display', 'none'); // <---- this is all I needed to add
      jQuery(element).slideDown(400, doneFn);
    },
    leave: function(element, doneFn) {
      console.log('exiting');
      jQuery(element).slideUp(400, doneFn);
    }
  }
}]);

app.animation('.yote', [function() {
  return {
    enter: function(element, doneFn) {
      jQuery(element).slideDown(400, doneFn);
    }
  }
}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.2.1" data-semver="3.2.1" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.2.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="ngAnimate@*" data-semver="1.4.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">

  <button ng-click="vm.click();">
    Click Me
  </button>
  <div class="yeet" style="background-color:green;" ng-if="vm.divExists">
    <h1>This part should slide in and out with button clicks.</h1>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```